# SQL how to check the type of a value before adding into a table using INSERT INTO?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to insert a value into my database if:

1. it is not null
2. it's only a number of any type (int, decimal...)

My query is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO my_table

(SELECT field_name, field_value FROM source_table WHERE field_value IS NOT NULL)
```

Let us say I have this table:

[image]

The only fields I am interested in adding in this example are f1 and f2.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Also note that your description and your query really have nothing in common.

Comment: @GordonLinoff check the edited question please

Comment: What is the datatype of the column field_val?

Comment: @NickW its type is `varchar`

Answer (score 3):

Just use the TRY_TO_NUMBER to convert the value and also add a WHERE clause "WHERE TRY_TO_NUMBER(field_val) is not null"